# Use typedef for passing parameters by reference

Tags: c, arrays, function, typedef

I have this part in instructions of my school project:

> In **hw_numbers.h** define type **hw_number_array** (for passing arguments to functions by reference). To store numbers in that array, use array of unsigned long.

My friend gave me hint, that it should look like this:

```
typedef unsigned long hw_number_array[];
```

Can someone explain me, why should I use this for passing an array to function?
And how can this type even exist without defining actual size of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the array is omitted, this is called an array of unknown bound.  There are only certain places where this can be used, but a function parameter is one of them.  There is a special rule that says even if a bound is given for an array, the bound is ignored and the parameter is equivalent to a pointer:

```
void f(int []) // this means void f(int *)
```

C++ inherited this rule from C.  Some programmers consider it helpful for documenting that it is intended that an array is passed for the parameter as opposed to a pointer to a single value.

When calling such a function, it appears that you can pass an array by reference:

```
{
    int a[5];
    f(a); // actually passes an int pointer
}
```

But this is actually an illusion.  The array decays to a pointer, and then a pointer is passed instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can try:

```
typedef unsigned long hw_number_array[];

int main()
{
    unsigned long myArray[100];

    setValue(myArray, 5, 10);
    unsigned long value = getValue(myArray, 5);

    return 0;
}

unsigned long setValue(hw_number_array a, int  index, unsigned long value)
{
    a[index] = value;
}


unsigned long getValue(hw_number_array a, int  index)
{
    return a[index];
}
```